# ManyToMany (with additional columns) using @ElementCollection and java.util.Map?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, many-to-many

I'm trying to optimize my `@Entity` classes. Let's take the common case of a `User <-> Group` relationship. I also want to store the date when the relation was established. The table layout:

```
 USER      GROUP_USER      GROUP
------    ------------    -------
 id        user_id         id
 name      group_id        name
           createdAt
```

With the following 3 classes:

1. `User` with `@OneToMany List<GroupUser>`
2. `GroupUser` with `@ManyToOne User` and `@ManyToOne Group`
3. `Group` with `@OneToMany List<GroupUser>`

It works, but it sucks for common use cases. For example: *Give me all groups for `User user`*:

```
List<Group> groups;
for(GroupUser gu : user.getGroupUsers) {
    groups.add(gu.getGroup());
}
```

---

Then the idea of using a `Map` came to my mind. So I created the following 3 classes:

```
@Entity
class User {
   @Column(name="id")
   UUID id;

   @Column(name="name")
   String name;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="Group_User")
   Map<Group, GroupUserRelationData> groups;
}

@Entity
class Group {
   @Column(name="id")
   UUID id;

   @Column(name="name")
   String name;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="Group_User")
   Map<User, GroupUserRelationData> users;
}

@Embeddable
class GroupUserRelationData {
  @Column(name="createdAt")
  DateTime createdAt;
}
```

It **does** create the 3 tables as expected, but the columns inside the `Group_User` table are weird:

```
 USER      GROUP_USER      GROUP
------    ------------    -------
 id        User_id         id
 name      users_KEY       name
           Group_id
           group_KEY
           createdAt
```

I'm sure that I'm missing some things... Looks like I have to specify the JoinColumn. But what's the right way?

What's the difference between `@CollectionTable(joinColumns=...)` and `@MapKeyColumn` and `@MapKeyJoinColumn`. Do I have to set all of those?

Or do I have to use `@ManyToMany` instead of `@ElementCollection` ?

I just want to get the same table layout as at the top using a `java.util.Map`.

---

**EDIT #1:** Additionally the database should afterwards have the right constraints for the table:

- Composite Primary Key (Group_id, User_id)

At the moment it creates a composite PK (Group_id, users_KEY) which seems pretty weird to me. And it also creates 4(!!) indexes, one for each column `User_id`, `Group_id`, `users_KEY` and `groups_KEY`.

---

**EDIT #2:** I found a website which tells when to use which annotations: http://kptek.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/collection-mapping/

The bad thing is: I still don't know **WHY**...

### Solution:

After a bit of trying I came up with the following code, which does exactly what I want. I've got to use all of those annotations, else it creates additional columns:

```
@Entity
class User {
   @Column(name="id")
   UUID id;

   @Column(name="name")
   String name;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="Group_User",
     joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="User_Id"))
   @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="Group_Id")
   Map<Group, GroupUserRelationData> groups;
}

@Entity
class Group {
   @Column(name="id")
   UUID id;

   @Column(name="name")
   String name;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="Group_User",
     joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Group_Id"))
   @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="User_Id")
   Map<User, GroupUserRelationData> users;
}

@Embeddable
class GroupUserRelationData {
  @Column(name="createdAt")
  DateTime createdAt;
}
```

**I'd still love to see an explanation what those annotations exactly do, and why the default behavior created FOUR columns and a strange primary key.**

Comment: Nice job. In addition, if you'd want to use non-entity as map generics, you'd also need `@MapKeyColumn(name="user")` and `@Column(name="data")`

Comment: if I understand right, `@MapKeyJoinColumn` equals `inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(...)` *within* `@JoinTable`, which seems to be another syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map required both the one-to-many key and the map-key.

In your first example, Hibernate figures out it needs a FK from `Group.id` to match the `GroupUser.group_id` to load the associated users. But because you don't specify a Map key it has to figure out [where to take it from](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#d5e5366)?

So, Hibernate assumed you wanted a `@MapKeyColumn` and because the column name was not specified, the name of the property followed by underscore followed by KEY is used (for example users_KEY).

That's why you had those two additional columns. When you supplied the `@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="User_Id")`, then the Map knew where to take the key from.